# Right justify roman page numbers in list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, koma-script, article, roman-numerals

I have a `scrartcl` document with arabic and roman page numbers. The list of tables looks like this:

[image: LOT]

Arabic page numbers are right justified (relative to each other), whereas roman numbers are centered.

**I would like to have all page numbers right justified,** like this (the red line is just for illustration):

[image: LOT - expected]

Although I suppose that the solution is probably related to the `listof` document options, I cannot find an appropriate setting. However, the problem also occurs with `article` instead of `scrartcl`, so it does not seem to be specific to KOMA script.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\clearpage

\begin{table}
\caption{First main table.}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{95}
\begin{table}
\caption{Second main table.}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{roman}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{table}
\caption{First appendix table.}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{28}
\begin{table}
\caption{Second appendix table.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The numbers are right justified, but the `\@pnumwidth` is too small

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution working for `article` and `scrartcl` (i.e. without using features of `KOMA`)

The page numbers are still right justified, but the width of the page number slot at the right margin is too small, because Roman numbers need more space to be typeset than arabic figures.

Increasing the value of `\@pnumwidth` will solve this problem, however, this will increase it for all `.toc` etc -- since Roman numbers are for all pages this should be no issue!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{40pt}% 40pt is just an example
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\listoftables
\clearpage

\begin{table}
\caption{First main table.}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{95}
\begin{table}
\caption{Second main table.}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{roman}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{table}
\caption{First appendix table.}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{28}
\begin{table}
\caption{Second appendix table.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great, thank you. Interestingly, the TOC does not need the setting, it can deal with the wide roman numbers by default. I therefore changed `@pnumwidth` only *after* TOC (and before LOT), thus TOC is not affected.

Comment: @CL: Yes, indeed -- I was looking at the wrong code actually. I'll remove my previous comment!